# Jquery toggleClass not toggling class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this div that displays 4 images and I am trying to get this jQuery function so that when I click on the image, it toggles a class which makes the image increase in size. Pretty simple, but I can't figure out why the code isn't toggling the `.exampleimgopen` class. I have linked the jquery script and all that to my html

```
<div id="examples">
    <p>Examples:</p>
    <img src="img/1.png" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="img/2.png" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="img/3.png" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="img/1.png" class="exampleimg">
</div>
```

The CSS for this code is:

```
#examples {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.exampleimg {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}

.exampleimg:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.exampleimgopen {
    width:600px;
}
```

And the jQuery for this is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#examples').click(function() {
        $('.exampleimg').toggleClass('.exampleimgopen');
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the dot in `toggleClass('.exampleimgopen')`, should be `toggleClass('exampleimgopen')`

Comment: Just tried that but now the whole function is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot in `toggleClass('.exampleimgopen')`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#examples').click(function() {
        $('.exampleimg').toggleClass('exampleimgopen');
    });
});
```

```css
#examples {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.exampleimg {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}

.exampleimg:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.exampleimgopen {
    width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="examples">
    <p>Examples:</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
</div>
```

If you want this on each image, do like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.exampleimg').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('exampleimgopen');
    });
});
```

```css
#examples {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.exampleimg {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
}

.exampleimg:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.exampleimgopen {
    width:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="examples">
    <p>Examples:</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" class="exampleimg">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thankyou, ill accept this answer when i can!

Comment: @RobertDeniro You're welcome. I also updated my answer with a 2:nd sample if you want it for each image individually

Answer (score 0):

This will toggle the class only for the clicked image. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#examples img.exampleimg').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('exampleimgopen');
        });
 });
```

Comment: `$('#examples').on('click','img.exampleimg', function(){` perhaps might be better